# use a style.css file from a .swc and build the Flex project with ANT

Tags: apache-flex, ant, stylesheet, swc, assets

I have an .SWC library with a style.css file inside.
The .SWC file is added to my project and the style.css is used this way:

```
<fx:Style source="assets/style/style.css" />
```

If I want to build my project with an ANT-script it says that "the external stylesheet couldn't be found".
In ANT you need to write the path for assets with an leading "/". So this would work:

```
<fx:Style source="/assets/style/style.css" />
```

But in this case it isn't possible to retrieve the style.css from the .swc as the compiler says that "the external stylesheet couldn't be found".

Is there any way to use the style.css inside the .swc AND use ANT to build the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved:
problem was within the compiled SWC.
I've forgotten to say the ant file to add the style. When I checked the SWC, I checked the SWC compiled by the Flash Builder and not by the ant script.